# Example for Yii public $loginRequiredAjaxResponse

Tags: php, yii

Problem
 1) when i request a page through ajax, i'm getting login page in response, the reason is session is expired. I can solve this issue by polling, but recently I came to know that yii gives solution for this like setting $loginRequiredAjaxResponse variable, i'm trying hard but i'm not able solve this, can anyone give me a example how actually to use. I am calling ajax request from my upload page.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you set "remember me" on login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the `components` section of your configuration file:

```
'user'=>array(
    'class'=>'WebUser',
    'loginRequiredAjaxResponse'=>'logged-out',
),
```

This gets output on any 403 via AJAX, rather than redirecting to login page.

Comment: Thank You very very much, struggling from few days didn't got, you'r post was helpful. Thank You again.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. But, not sure how to use this in my controller action as I am newbie.